# Parse migrate button not working

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, database-migration, mlab

Because of the recent announcement of Parse.com's shutdown, I'm trying to move my data into a Mongolab instance. I've created the db, copied the url and changed the dbuser and dbpassword appropriately. Then I've entered the changed url into the Parse migration tool (located in Parse.com at app settings -> general -> migrate) and nothing seems to happen. I don't get any kind of verification or anything. Please help!
[image: parse migration error (stalling)]